# Share class between components using a service in Angular

Tags: angular

I have the following class in Angular that I want to share between two child components:

```
export class DatasetsMetadata {
    Name!: string;
    Code!: string;
    Frequency!: string;
}
```

I want to share the data using a service in Angular, using something like this:

```
import { DatasetsMetadata } from './datasets-metadata'; 
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OodlerService {
  
  private selectedDataset = new DatasetsMetadata();
  
  constructor() { }
  
  setSelectedDataset(selection: DatasetsMetadata) {
    this.selectedDataset.Code = selection.Code;
    this.selectedDataset.Name = selection.Name;
    this.selectedDataset.Frequency = selection.Frequency;
  };

  getSelectedDataset(): DatasetsMetadata {
    return this.selectedDataset;
  }
}
```

I then want to write the data to the service when it changes in one component, something like this example:

```
  onSelection(event: any){
    this.CurrentDataset.Code = event.option.value;
    this.CurrentDataset.Name = event.option.name;
    this.CurrentDataset.Frequency = "Default";
    this.Model.setSelectedDataset(this.CurrentDataset); 
  };
```

The above code seems to write the data to the service correctly if I check it by logging the data to the console. However, it fails when I try to read the data in another component using something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { OodlerService } from '../oodler.service';
import { DatasetsMetadata } from '../datasets-metadata';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-oodler-chart',
  templateUrl: './oodler-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./oodler-chart.component.css'],
  providers: [OodlerService]
})

export class OodlerChartComponent {

  constructor (private http: HttpClient, private Model: OodlerService){}

  getMetadata(): void {
    var metadata = this.Model.getSelectedDataset();
    console.log(metadata.Code);
  }
```

What is failing is that I get back undefined for the metadata variable in the getMetadata() method. The problem seems to be I am creating a new instance of the service in the OodlerChartComponent. For example, if I add a method to the service that returns static data like the getText() method below, it successfully returns the string "test string".

```
  getText(): string {
    return "test string";
  }
```

I've tried it a number of ways, including create a member in the OodlerChartComponent class of type DatasetsMetadata rather than using the local variable, but nothing has worked so far. Can anyone explain how to do this properly?

Comment: Did you by any chance provide service in a module? Could make another service instance, which wouldn't have the data.

Comment: @BojanKogoj I agree with you but it seems the `OodlerService ` is `providedIn: 'root'`.

Comment: Hi Bojan, I did not create any modules in the code. I did miss a key piece of code where I inject the service into the constructor of the OodlerChartComponent. The problem seems to be that I am creating a new instance of the service in the OodlerChartComponent rather than using the same service to which I which I called the setSelectedDataset() function in the other component.

Comment: Bojan and SJNF, I'm not quite following you. Are you recommending that I create the service in a module instead of root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove

```
providers: [OodlerService]
```

This creates a new instance on the level of that component, but you've already provided it in root (whether that's "ideal" is a different question and depends on the use case).